# Enable / Disable dropdown list based on another dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have two dropdown lists.

```
    <select id="cat_user">             
     <option value="Super Admin">Super Admin</option>
     <option value="Event Admin">Event Admin</option>
    </select>
```

```
    <select id="event_name">             
     <option value="ICT">ICT</option>
     <option value="Fun Run">Fun Run</option>
    </select>
```

I want that the second drop-down list should get enabled only if we choose `Event Admin` in the first drop-down list. It should again get disabled if we deselect the `Event Admin` from the first drop-down list.

> May I know how can this be achieved using javascript?

Comment: First Welcome to StackOverFlow did  you tried anything to achieve what you needed if you tried any thing please add it to the question if you didn't you can google your problem first then add what your tried as it's better for your benefit

Comment: Why was this voted down? It's a great question, one which I spent a few hours googling before coming across this question which addresses  EXACTLY what I'm working on currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to handle dropdown change event.

```
<script>

$('#cat_user').change(function(){

   if($('#cat_user option:selected').text() == "Event Admin")
   {
     $('#event_name').prop('disabled',false);
   }
   else
   {
     $('#event_name').prop('disabled',true);
   }
 });

</script>
```

you can refere below link for working demo

https://jsfiddle.net/t7jswp8r/

Comment: Please mark answer as verified so other people can find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jquery, you can do something like this in your Javascript,

```
document.getElementById('event_name').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('cat_user').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    if(event.target.value === "Event Admin") {
    document.getElementById('event_name').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('event_name').disabled = true;
  }
})
```

Comment: Please mark answer as verified if it solved your problem.